# AngularJS App on Windows Server 2012's IIS is not redndering

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, iis

This is my first question on this site and I apologize if I break any rule.

I have an angularjs app (using ASP.NET Web API) that I am able to run successfully on the IIS of my local machine (Windows 7) but after I deployed it to the IIS of a Windows Server 2012 machine, the index.html file just wasn't rendered. It will show contents like:

{{title}} and other angular's binding {{xxxxx}} contents.

It appears the javaScript scripts are not executed.

I checked all my folder's permission (IIS_IUSRS etc), they are all have read and execute right.

Is there any IIS configuration that I didn't set correctly?

TIA

Cheers.

Comment: When you pull up the site in Chrome and check the developer tools do you see any errors or messages that might indicate an issue?

Comment: That is the strange thing, there is not a single error displayed on the F12 console. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Does the network tab show that your .js files are being sent to the client?

Comment: Most probably it may be due to relative path for script files is not correct.

Comment: Lex, I am on a server that only has IE 11 (was not allowed to install chrome) so I couldn't check that out.

Comment: Pankaj, I was first suspect that, but then how could that work on the Windows 7's IIS?

Comment: Lex,  I did see the network tab on the IE, nothing there either.

Comment: Have the static content handling modules been installed on the Windows 2012 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tearing my hairs off for a couple of days I finally solved my problem. It turns out, as I first suspected, an IIS configuration issue. I'll need to turn on most options (except CGI) in the Application Development Roles from the IIS's role features list.

One more hurdle is I also need to register the ASP.net on the system, like so:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Cheers!